# Will Google index my VPS without a DNS?

Tags: dns, vps

I am about to upload my site to a VPS.  I do not want Google to index my site yet - I simply want to test my site using the IP address the VPS returns to me.  I know that I can use robots.txt to prevent Google from indexing my site, **but will Google even find my site** if I do not point a DNS to my VPS?

Comment: Not necessarily DNS, but any public links to it will cause search engines to go have a look. As long as you keep the link private you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks Abe.  Appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Google, and any other search engine will find your site if there is some other site on the internet that has a link pointing to it. If there's no link, Google will not find it. On the other way, when there is a link, it doesn't matter if it contains only an IP address or a domain name. However I suppose that on the search results, Google prefers sites with valid DNS names to IP-only sites.